# How to use React useRef hook with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-hooks

I am creating a reference using the new useRef hook

`const anchorEl = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)`

And using like

```
<div style={{ width: "15%", ...flexer, justifyContent: "flex-end" }}>
    <Popover
        id="simple-popper"
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={() => {
          setOpen(false)
        }}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'center',
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'center',
        }}
    >
        <Typography>The content of the Popover.</Typography>
    </Popover>
</div>
<div ref={anchorEl} >
      ...
```

but I get this error

```
TS2322: Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement | ((element: HTMLElement) => HTMLElement)'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>' is not assignable to type '(element: HTMLElement) => HTMLElement'.
    Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>' provides no match for the signature '(element: HTMLElement): HTMLElement'.
Version: typescript 3.2.2, tslint 5.12.0
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`anchorEl` variable is ref object, an object that has only `current` property. It's unknown how `Popover` works but, but it expects an element as `anchorEl` prop, not a ref.

It should be:

```
<Popover
    id="simple-popper"
    open={open}
    anchorEl={anchorEl.current}
```

If `<Popover` and `<div ref={anchorEl} >` are siblings like it's shown, a ref won't be ready to use at the moment when it's passed as a prop. In this case a component needs to be re-rendered on mount:

```
const [, forceUpdate] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  forceUpdate({});
}, []);

...

   { anchorEl.current && <Popover
        id="simple-popper"
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl.current}
        ...
   }
   <div ref={anchorEl} >
```

In case `<div ref={anchorEl} >` doesn't have to be rendered to DOM, it could be

```
   <Popover
        id="simple-popper"
        open={open}
        anchorEl={<div/>}
```

The necessity to render a component twice and use `forceUpdate` workaround suggests that this could be done in a better way. The actual problem here is that `Popover` accepts an element as a prop, while accepting refs is common in React.

At this point ref object has no benefits. [Ref callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) can be used with `useState` instead, state update function is callback that receives new state as an argument and it doesn't cause additional updates if it receives the same state (DOM element):

```
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<HTMLDivElement>(null);

...

   { anchorEl && <Popover
        id="simple-popper"
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        ...
   }
   <div ref={setAnchorEl} >
```

Comment: Great answer. In TypeScript, you'd have to pass a value to forceUpdate. I used null.

Comment: Do you have to write ugly react in order to overcome a typescript compilation issue??

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis Can you clarify? The question had compilation error because there was a mistake in code. A fix was suggested. It would be the same for JS.

Comment: @EstusFlask I think it could be done better using anchorEl.current as a dependency in useEffect, and set a state to the value of anchorEl.current from within this useEffect. That would trigger a rerender implicity without having to force it. My point is that it could look less of a hack

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis Do you mean something `useEffect(() => { forceUpdate(anchorEl.current) }, [anchorEl.current])`? Doesn't seem much better to me. Could be done in more simple way with useState alone, updated the post. Any way, this isn't specific to TS, compilation error just shown the issue that already was there.

Comment: honestly, i dont think this is an acceptable answer. while this might get the job done this will cause problems in big projects.

Comment: @loekTheDreamer What problems exactly? I don't see how this isn't an acceptable answer. The question is about how to use a ref, and that's how. The last snippet is the way it's supposed to be done. I could agree that putting div container next to Popover may be impractical, but this wasn't discussed.

Comment: setting empty state just because you need to re-render is bad programming.

Comment: @loekTheDreamer There is an in-built type in React for `useRef` return value. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74651338/8810941

Comment: "setting empty state just because you need to re-render is bad programming." Especially because you do not need it as react is already re-rendering if you use refs (pass refs to html vdom elems).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `MutableRefObject` type from 'react'

```js
import { MutableRefObject } from "react"

const anchorEl: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement> = React.useRef(null);
```

Another way to enforce types for refs would be to use `ElementRef`. [1]

```js
import { useRef, ElementRef } from "react";
 
const Component = () => {
  const audioRef = useRef<ElementRef<"audio">>(null);
 
  return <audio ref={audioRef}>Hello</audio>;
};
```

[1] https://www.totaltypescript.com/strongly-type-useref-with-elementref

Comment: Can you explain why it works here?

Comment: Can I know what did you mean by asking to explain? It's just the type for ref elements defined by React. There's nothing more to explain here I guess :).

Comment: that's ("the type for ref elements defined by React") what I asked haha thanks

Comment: Why is this type not returned by default?

Comment: "Why is this type not returned by default?" It is, `const anchorEl = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>();` is the same (although it contains the type `undefined | HTMLDivElement` instead of `null | HTMLDivElement` from the example)